# How do I access DOM using keyboard shortcuts in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have a 50x50 px `div` element and I want to change its background color when I hit Ctrl+K. How do I do it?

---

**UPDATE :** After searching around for a bit, I tried this code and it still isn't working

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="d" style="background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>
    <script>
        const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
        ipcRenderer.on('changeCol', (event,color) => {
            document.getElementById('d').style.backgroundColor = color;
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the main.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
const globalShortcut = electron.globalShortcut;

let mainWindow 

function createWindow () {
      mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
      mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

      mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
            mainWindow = null
      })
}

app.on('ready', function() {
    createWindow();

    // registered a shortcut for Ctrl+K
    globalShortcut.register('Control+K', () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fininsh-load', () => {
            mainWindow.webContents.send('changeCol','green');
        })
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
      if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
      }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
      if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
      }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I figured out I can't modify DOM directly from the main.js file. We have to use `webContents.send()` and `ipcRenderer` to send and recieve asynchronous messages via channels. Here's some simple code which lets you modify a `div`'s background color.

main.js

```
app.on('ready', function() {
    globalShortcut.register('A', () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('changeColor','green');
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<script>
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
ipcRenderer.on('changeColor', (event,col) => {
    var element = document.getElementById('element');
    element.style.color = col;
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably by using the [Accelerator Api](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/accelerator/)

```
const {app, globalShortcut} = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
  // Register a 'Control+K' shortcut listener.
  globalShortcut.register('Control+K', () => {
    // Do stuff when K and Command is pressed.
  })
})
```

Then just some simple javascript where it says `// Do stuff when K and Command is pressed.` This is going to depend how your HTML/CSS is set up and the exact results you're looking for.

Comment: I am using the accelerator API and I still can't get it to work. I can open dialogs but can't access DOM for some reason. I've updated my post with some code for more info.